# how to use a predefined variable in a subscript in HTML

Tags: html, google-maps, variables

I have this Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">          
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var directionDisplay;
var map;


function initialize() {
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var copenhagen = new google.maps.LatLng(55.6771, 12.5704);
var myOptions = {
    zoom:12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: copenhagen
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}


var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function calcRoute() {
var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");

var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
    }
});
}
</script>

<title>Distance Calculator</title>

<style type="text/css">

        body {
            font-family:Helvetica, Arial;
        }
        #map_canvas {
            height: 50%;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<body onload="initialize()">
<p>Enter your current location and desired destination to get the distance</p>
    <div>
        <p>
            <label for="start">Start: </label>
            <input type="text" name="start" id="start" />
<br>
            <label for="end">End:  </label>
            <input type="text" name="end" id="end" />

            <input type="submit" value="Calculate Route" onclick="calcRoute()" />
        </p>
        <p>
<script>

                 var cost=distance*2-(distance*2*0.20)

                 document.write("Cost: ");
                 document.write(cost + "<br>");


</script>
    </p>
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the code in Question is this:

```
<script>

                 var cost=distance*2-(distance*2*0.20)

                 document.write("Cost: ");
                 document.write(cost + "<br>");


</script>
```

This Code asks the user for a starting address and a destination address and calculates the distance between the two points using Google Maps API. I then Added in functionality to calculate how much a taxi would cost to go that distance using their formula for regional flat rates (distance in km)*2-20%.

My problem lies in the fact that the "distance" variable is defined within the API code, so when i refer to it while calculating the cost, it doesn't seem to carry over.... like it doesn't even exist. I know it has something to do with it being defined inside a different subscript than the one trying to use it. Any and all advice is appreciated!

Comment: How does the title relate to the question? The question mentions a subscript at the end, but there does not seem to be any subscript around.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I intended to mention that I thought the problem was because the <script> and </Script> tags contained the code where the "distance" variable was defined and and that it could not be referenced outside those tags. I suppose when i was typing up this post originally, i was thinking of the script that was indented on its own as "Sub" script aha! i must be losing it!

Comment: honestly im not too sure if there is a proper name for "indented code incased by <script> tags" so if you could adjust the title to one more suitable and relevant to the question then please help me out here

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for. Hope it helps.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">          
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var directionDisplay;
var map;


function initialize() {
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var copenhagen = new google.maps.LatLng(55.6771, 12.5704);
var myOptions = {
    zoom:12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: copenhagen
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}


var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function calcRoute() {
var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");

var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;

        var cost=distanceInput.value*2-(distanceInput.value*2*0.20)
        var costDiv = document.getElementById("cost");
        costDiv.style.display = "";
        costDiv.innerHTML = "Cost: "+cost + "<br>";
    }
});
}
</script>

<title>Distance Calculator</title>

<style type="text/css">

        body {
            font-family:Helvetica, Arial;
        }
        #map_canvas {
            height: 50%;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<body onload="initialize()">
<p>Enter your current location and desired destination to get the distance</p>
    <div>
        <p>
            <label for="start">Start: </label>
            <input type="text" name="start" id="start" />
<br>
            <label for="end">End:  </label>
            <input type="text" name="end" id="end" />
            <input type="hidden" name="distance" id="distance" >
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate Route" onclick="calcRoute()" />
            <div style="display:none;" id="cost"></div>
        </p>
        <p>

    </p>
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Here's how you can get the minimum distance and the cost associated with it. First thing, you have to make the request to Google Maps API provideRouteAlternatives = true, otherwise you will get only one route as the response. Second, I do think that Google is returning the routes sorted by their distance in ascending order - not totally sure about that, but you can possibly assume that the first route **is** the route with minimum distance. In any case, here is one way of doing what you want.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">          
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var directionDisplay;
var map;


function initialize() {
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var copenhagen = new google.maps.LatLng(55.6771, 12.5704);
var myOptions = {
    zoom:12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: copenhagen
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}


var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function calcRoute() {
var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");

var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    provideRouteAlternatives: true
};

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        if(response.routes[0] != undefined && response.routes[0].legs[0] != undefined) {
            /* Take the min distance route */
            / * Assume the first distance is the shortest */
            var lowestDistance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
            for(var i =0; i<response.routes.length;i=i+1) {
            console.log(response.routes[i].legs[0].distance.value);
                if(lowestDistance <= response.routes[i].legs[0].distance.value) {
                    lowestDistance = response.routes[i].legs[0].distance.value;
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    distanceInput.value = response.routes[i].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;

                    var cost=distanceInput.value*2-(distanceInput.value*2*0.20)
                    var costDiv = document.getElementById("cost");
                    costDiv.style.display = "";
                    costDiv.innerHTML = "Cost: "+cost + "<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
}
</script>

<title>Distance Calculator</title>

<style type="text/css">

        body {
            font-family:Helvetica, Arial;
        }
        #map_canvas {
            height: 50%;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<body onload="initialize()">
<p>Enter your current location and desired destination to get the distance</p>
    <div>
        <p>
            <label for="start">Start: </label>
            <input type="text" name="start" id="start" />
<br>
            <label for="end">End:  </label>
            <input type="text" name="end" id="end" />
            <input type="hidden" name="distance" id="distance" >
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate Route" onclick="calcRoute()" />
            <div style="display:none;" id="cost"></div>
        </p>
        <p>

    </p>
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That calculates the Cost Perfectly! however in situations where there are multiple routes to get to the desired location, how would i make it choose the route with the shortest distance? (the lowest km)

Comment: I tried the code you suggested but it still just recieves the first available route and then calculates it from there. It would be ideal if there were a way to request all possible routes, sort them by distance and then display them in a pop up list

Comment: The code is receiving all the possible routes, however, it filters down on the shortest one. You need to change/remove that filtering logic and apply your own additional logic of displaying all the possible options.